# Baby food in checked bags?

Tags: luggage

Can you check baby food? Or will it spoil? Not sure how hot or cold its gets. I have a special needs son who will only eat certain foods. We are traveling from Cincinnati to Florida. Very short flight about 2 hours. We are staying at Disney World. They pick you up from the airport. So everything you do is on their transportation. And I know TSA want you bring a weeks worth of baby food and carry on. Has anyone checked baby food before?

Comment: Depends on the type of foods you are taking.  Most baby food in its original packaging will do just fine (most is sold on non-refrigerated store shelves)

Comment: Is there a missing "won't" in the question?

Answer (score 1):

**It should be fine.** The airplane hold temperature is generally set to be anywhere between 5 and 25 deg C, so cool but above freezing.

I'd advise you to freeze the food if possible and pack it well in an insulated cooler bag or equivalent. You could even check it in separately in a Styrofoam box filled with ice if you want.

The one caveat is that if your flight is badly delayed or cancelled, the bag may sit around on tarmac for a long time in uncontrolled conditions. This is unlikely to be an issue for a single, non-stop flight though.